# How To Read Security Options "System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hasing and signing" Programmatically

Tags: c#, gpo, local-security-authority

I am developing a windows service from where i cannot read registry. So i am looking forward for code solution to check whether machine is FIPS compliant or not.

[image: Security Options].

if you could see the highlighted entry in the image. That particular entry i have to read from the code.

How To Read Security Options "System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hasing and signing" Programmatically. Where in RSOP I should query?

Comment: Please type the highlighted text into your question as text, so people can read it. A screenshot is no good, but a full-page screenshot with acres of irrelevant icons and toolbars is a bit much. You don't seem inclined to put forth much effort here.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty workaround to detect if FIPS algorithms are enforced may be to use one that is known to be non FIPS complaint like **RijndaelManaged**.
If enforcement is enabled it will throw an exception explicitly saying it's because of FIPS compliancy.

Dirty, but it may solve your problem...

Comment: Thanks Monteleone.